# setting up cassandra multi node cluster: 'Nodes have the same token 0'

Tags: cassandra, installation, cluster-computing

I'm trying to set up a Cassandra multi node cluster in my computer just to test, but it seems not work... The Cassandra version is 1.1 and It runs on Ubuntu.

Fist of all, I've modified the cassandra.yaml file for each node as follows:

**node0**

- initial_token: 0
- seeds: "127.0.0.1"
- listen_address: 127.0.0.1
- rpc_address: 0.0.0.0
- endpoint_snitch: RackInferringSnitch

**node1**

same as *node0* exept for:

- initial_token: 28356863910078205288614550619314017621 *(get using
  cassandra token generator)*
- listen_address: 127.0.0.2

---

After that, I've started first the seed node 127.0.0.1 and, once the node is up, I've started the other node 127.0.0.2. I've got the following:

[...]

INFO 06:09:27,146 Listening for thrift clients...

INFO 06:09:27,909 Node /127.0.0.1 is now part of the cluster

INFO 06:09:27,911 InetAddress /127.0.0.1 is now UP

INFO 06:09:27,913 Nodes /127.0.0.1 and /127.0.0.2 have the same token 0.  Ignoring /127.0.0.1

---

Running *nodetool -h localhost ring* it shows:

Address: 127.0.0.2

DC:    datacenter1

Rack:  rack1

Status: Up

State:  Normal

Load:   11,21 KB

Owns:   100,00%

Token:  0

As you can see, only the information of the second node is showed owning 100% of the ring. Indeed, the token is initialized to 0 instead of to the value I defined at its cassandra.yaml file.

---

The gossip Info is:

/127.0.0.2

LOAD:25559.0

STATUS:NORMAL,0

SCHEMA:59adb24e-f3cd-3e02-97f0-5b395827453f

RELEASE_VERSION:1.1.6-SNAPSHOT

RPC_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0

/127.0.0.1

LOAD:29859.0

STATUS:NORMAL,0

SCHEMA:59adb24e-f3cd-3e02-97f0-5b395827453f

RELEASE_VERSION:1.1.6-SNAPSHOT

RPC_ADDRESS:0.0.0.0

---

Does anyone know what is happening and how can I fix it?
Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

initial_token is only checked at first startup, when it is written to a system table.  Delete the system table files and restart.

Comment: still facing the same issue. After deleting the system table from data folder.